# How to sort an object list retrieved from fire base?

Tags: html, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I am fairly new to firebase and I noticed since firebase does not really store arrays I cannot sort them in the same way I would sort an array. I have an object list stored in firebase that contains a date and time and I want to sort it according to them from lowest to highest.

I have retrieved the data but I do not know how to sort it. This is how my data looks like on firebase: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vajsj.jpg

Note: If possible after sorting the list I would like to know how to group all appointments that fall under the same date.

```js
Appointments;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public firebase: FirebaseProvider) {
  this.Appointments = this.firebase.getAppointments();
}

getAppointments() {
  return this.afdb.list('/Apointments/');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<ng-container *ngFor='let a of Appointments|async'>
  <ion-card>
    <button ion-item>
      Time:&nbsp;{{a.Time}}<br/>
      Number of available maids: &nbsp;{{a.NoOfMaids}}
    </button>
  </ion-card>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Firebase Realtime DB doesn't allow you to perform queries, you can checkout Firestore which could be a better alternative.
2. You can model data in a different way to make this possible
   Right now you are storing Appointments>Id>Data
   Instead you can store like Appointments>Date>Ids>Data
   This way you can directly query for a specific date.
3. Get the snapshot of at the ref /Appointments and transform into an array and sort locally

Comment: Question about the second point. If i model it like that how would I call/retrieve the Date under Appointments?

Comment: So moving the date up will let you directly ref(Appointments/Date), or if you ref by Appointments then you get a collection of ids grouped by date

Comment: I understand the idea behind it but I do not know how to apply it with code could you show me if possible?

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you want to achieve so I might help with a snippet

Comment: So I remodeled my data as you suggested. Now I want to call all the data under appointments that are stored, but I want it so that the appointments are grouped under their appropriate dates and are sorted according date and time.

Comment: So when you get the appointments, you will do somthing var ref = firebase.database().ref("applicants"); on this ref you will add on value event, so the key will be your date and the val will be actual data. Check this example - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot

Comment: Okay so I have another question this is how I usaully call me data from firebase:- return this.afdb.list('/Appointments/'). Now if I want to call a specific date it goes like this return this.afdb.list('/Appointments/'+'date i need'). So my question is If i want to iterate appointments and call all the dates stored under it do you know how I can do it using this method of calling(return this.afdb.list('/Appointments/'+.......);)?

Comment: when you call this.afdb.list('/Appointments') you already have all appointments grouped by date, flatten in to single array, you can locally apply any filter you want locally. Also you can consider adding the date as well into the object, so that you dont need to keep a track of the group.The best way is to move it to Firestore, you can query & sort this data easily.